# How to do weighted softmax output custom op in mxnet?

Tags: python, mxnet

I want to replace mx.symbol.SoftmaxOutput with the weighted version (assign different weight respect to label's frequency in the whole dataset)

The original function works well like below:

```
cls_prob = mx.symbol.SoftmaxOutput(data=data,
                                   label=label,
                                   multi_output=True,
                                   normalization='valid',
                                   use_ignore=True, 
                                   ignore_label=-1,
                                   name='cls_prob')
```

The current code I wrote as below. The code can run without errors, but the loss quickly explode to nan. I am dealing with detection problem, RCNNL1 loss with quickly become nan when I use my code as CustomOp.
Another thing is that I have to ignore label -1 and I am not sure how to do it properly. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import mxnet as mx
import numpy as np

class WeightedSoftmaxCrossEntropyLoss(mx.operator.CustomOp):
    def __init__(self, num_class):
        self.num_class = int(num_class)

    def forward(self, is_train, req, in_data, out_data, aux):

        data = in_data[0]
        label = in_data[1]
        pred = mx.nd.SoftmaxOutput(data, label, multi_output=True,
                               normalization='valid', use_ignore=True, ignore_label=-1,
                               name='rcnn_cls_prob')

        self.assign(out_data[0], req[0], pred)

    def backward(self, req, out_grad, in_data, out_data, in_grad, aux):
        cls_weight = np.array([
            0.002852781814876101, 
            0.30715984513157385, 
            1.0932468996115976, 
            1.1598757152765971, 
            0.20739109264009636, 
            1.1984256112776808, 
            0.18746186040248036, 
            2.9009928470737023, 
            0.92140970338602113, 
            1.200317380251021
        ])
        label = in_data[1]
        pred = out_data[0]
        label = label.asnumpy().astype('int32').reshape((-1))
        pred = pred.asnumpy().reshape((pred.shape[0], pred.shape[1], -1)).transpose((0, 2, 1))
        pred = pred.reshape((label.shape[0], -1))

        # Need to ignore label (how)
        out_inds = np.where(label == -1)[0]
        #label = label[keep_inds]
        one_hot = np.zeros((label.shape[0], self.num_class))
        one_hot[np.arange(label.shape[0]), label] = 1
        # gradient
        dx = pred - one_hot
        #dx[out_inds] = 0.0
        weighted_dx = cls_weight * dx / 4
        self.assign(in_grad[0], req[0], weighted_dx)

@mx.operator.register("weighted_softmax_ce_loss")
class WeightedSoftmaxCrossEntropyLossProp(mx.operator.CustomOpProp):
    def __init__(self, num_class):
        super(WeightedSoftmaxCrossEntropyLossProp, self).__init__(need_top_grad=False)
        self.num_class = num_class

    def list_arguments(self):
        return ['data', 'label']

    def list_outputs(self):
        return ['output']

    def infer_shape(self, in_shapes):
        data_shape = in_shapes[0]
        label_shape = (in_shapes[0][0],)
        output_shape = in_shapes[0]
        return [data_shape, label_shape], [output_shape], []

    def create_operator(self, ctx, in_shapes, in_dtypes):
        #  create and return the CustomOp class.
        `enter code here`return WeightedSoftmaxCrossEntropyLoss(self.num_class)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if using a customop here would be the best as it may be slow. 
Because SoftmaxOuput computes the gradient in the backward pass, it is not convenient to multiply losses as you want to do.
However, it is not too complicated to do with the symbolic API. I have attached a toy example, hope it helps.

```py
import mxnet as mx
import numpy as np
import logging

# learn floor function from random numbers in [-1, -1 + num_classes]
n = 10000
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
x = (np.random.random((n,)) * num_classes) - 1
y = np.floor(x)
print(x[:2])
print(y[:2])

# define graph
data = mx.symbol.Variable('data')
label = mx.symbol.Variable('label')
class_weights = mx.symbol.Variable('class_weights')
fc = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=data, num_hidden=num_classes)
fc = mx.sym.Activation(data=fc, act_type='relu')
proba = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=fc, num_hidden=num_classes)
proba = mx.sym.softmax(proba)

# multipy cross entropy loss by weight
cross_entropy = -mx.sym.pick(proba, label) * mx.sym.pick(class_weights, label)

# mask the loss to zero when label is -1
mask = mx.sym.broadcast_not_equal(label, mx.sym.ones_like(label) * -1)
cross_entropy = cross_entropy * mask

# fit module
class_weights = np.array([np.arange(1, 1 + num_classes)]*n) 
data_iter = mx.io.NDArrayIter(data={'data': x, 'class_weights': class_weights}, label={'label': y}, batch_size=batch_size)
mod = mx.mod.Module(
    mx.sym.Group([mx.sym.MakeLoss(cross_entropy, name='ce_loss'), mx.sym.BlockGrad(proba)]),
    data_names=[v.name for v in data_iter.provide_data],
    label_names=[v.name for v in data_iter.provide_label]
)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
mod.bind(data_shapes=data_iter.provide_data, label_shapes=data_iter.provide_label)
mod.init_params()
mod.fit(
    data_iter, 
    num_epoch=200, 
    optimizer=mx.optimizer.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, rescale_grad=1.0/batch_size),
    batch_end_callback=mx.callback.Speedometer(batch_size, 200), 
    eval_metric=mx.metric.Loss(name="loss", output_names=["ce_loss_output"]))

# show result, -1 are not predicted correctly as we did not compute their loss
probas = mod.predict(data_iter)[1].asnumpy()
print(zip(x, np.argmax(probas, axis=1)))
```

Comment: Thasnks, it help me a lot. I will try it to see if it works. Another question regarding that you said the custom op may be slow ? Is it because using asnumpy() to swap memory into cpu ?

I have modified weighted softmax entropy loss in caffe, is it possible to port it into mxnet ? thanks !

Comment: Yes. For Cafe, I have not tried to port models maybe you can try onnx for that https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ai/announcing-the-availability-of-onnx-1-0/

Comment: @geoalgo Thanks for this great answer! Could you please explain how passing mx.sym.Group([mx.sym.MakeLoss(cross_entropy, name='ce_loss'), mx.sym.BlockGrad(proba)]) to the module makes it understand that the first element is loss and the second element is the network's output? In addition, why do you block the gradients to the second parameter?

Comment: Grouping allows to tell the module several outputs needs to be computed at each forward pass. 
This allows you to extract the probabilities later on when you call 'mod.predict(data_iter)[1]' which does a forward pass and extract the second element of the group. BlockGrad is required as no gradient should be computed from the probabilities. You need to tell nothing has to been done in the backward for this output, otherwise if I am not mistaken, mxnet will just minimize your probabilities :-)

Comment: Now you may wonder about the difference with SoftmaxOutput which doesnt require this grouping. This is a bit confusing but SoftmaxOutput computes the output in the forward pass and the loss in the backward pass: it prevents you from the need to do this grouping trick but makes it trickier to get the loss.

Comment: `cross_entropy = -mx.sym.pick(proba, label) * mx.sym.pick(class_weights, label)` This line doesn't compute cross entropy loss of proba and label, which should be `label*log(proba)`.