# A weighted version of SoftmaxOutput in mxnet

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, mxnet

I am training a neural network in mxnet that does classification, and I would like to put more weight on some of the classes. So besically, I would like to use a weighted version of [mxnet.symbol.SoftmaxOutput](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/symbol.html#mxnet.symbol.SoftmaxOutput). As a toy example, I used a simplified version of [this mnist code](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/python/mnist.html).

Here is the code that defines the network

```
import mxnet as mx
mnist = mx.test_utils.get_mnist()

batch_size = 100
train_iter = mx.io.NDArrayIter(mnist['train_data'], mnist['train_label'], batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_iter = mx.io.NDArrayIter(mnist['test_data'], mnist['test_label'], batch_size)

data = mx.sym.var('data')
data = mx.sym.flatten(data=data)


fc1  = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=data, num_hidden=15)
act1 = mx.sym.Activation(data=fc1, act_type="relu")

# MNIST has 10 classes
fc2  = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=act1, num_hidden=10)
# Softmax with cross entropy loss
mlp  = mx.sym.SoftmaxOutput(data=fc2, name='softmax')
```

And here is the code that trains the network:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # logging to stdout
# create a trainable module on CPU
mlp_model = mx.mod.Module(symbol=mlp, context=mx.cpu())
mlp_model.fit(train_iter,  # train data
              eval_data=val_iter,  # validation data
              optimizer='sgd',  # use SGD to train
              optimizer_params={'learning_rate':0.1},  # use fixed learning rate
              eval_metric='acc',  # report accuracy during training
              batch_end_callback = mx.callback.Speedometer(batch_size, 100), # output progress for each 100 data batches
              num_epoch=1)  # train for at most 10 dataset passes
```

Now let's say that I want to put more weight on the digit 0. I added the following lines right below the definition of `mlp`:

```
weight=[[5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
weight_sym  = mx.symbol.Variable(name="weight",
     init=mx.init.Constant(weight), attr={}, shape=(1,10))

mlp=mx.sym.broadcast_mul(mlp,weight_sym)
```

Then when I tried to train, I got the error:

> TypeError: NDArray does not support assignment with [[5, 1, 1, 1, 1,
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] of type

What would be the proper way to do that?

Comment: Quite related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427500 note that there is a solution which does not require to have a customop.

Answer (score 3):

There is no out-of-the-box implementation of the weighted softmax in  MxNet, but the same people, who have contributed a lot to MxNet, have developed an example, which uses weighted softmax for 2 classes (basically, it is weighted logistic regression). You can take a look into their implementation here - https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/df558290930f9f3ed6941c306b5cc650505f7481/example/sparse/linear_classification/weighted_softmax_ce.py

The example introduces a new Custom Operation, that takes one value - a weight of a positive class. I have taken their code an adjusted it to your use case - passing an array of weights instead of a single value. Unfortunately, you cannot pass anything besides a string into a custom operation's constructor. That's why the class_weights_value is defined as a string and there is an ugly conversion into nd.array in the code.

This code won't be as fast as original Softmax, which is written in a highly optimized fashion in C:

```
import mxnet as mx


class WeightedSoftmaxCrossEntropyLoss(mx.operator.CustomOp):
    """ softmax cross entropy weighted loss, where the loss is adjusted by \
(class_weight) / sum_of_all_weights)

    """

    def __init__(self, class_weights):
        # parse initial weights from a string to separate items
        self.class_weights = mx.nd.array([float(x) for x in class_weights.split(',')])
        # scale weights, so they would add up to 1
        self.class_scales = self.class_weights / len(self.class_weights)

    def forward(self, is_train, req, in_data, out_data, aux):
        """Implements forward computation.

        is_train : bool, whether forwarding for training or testing.
        req : list of {'null', 'write', 'inplace', 'add'}, how to assign to out_data. 'null' means skip assignment, etc.
        in_data : list of NDArray, input data.
        out_data : list of NDArray, pre-allocated output buffers.
        aux : list of NDArray, mutable auxiliary states. Usually not used.
        """
        data = in_data[0]
        label = in_data[1]
        pred = mx.nd.SoftmaxOutput(data, label)
        self.assign(out_data[0], req[0], pred)

    def backward(self, req, out_grad, in_data, out_data, in_grad, aux):
        """Implements backward computation

        req : list of {'null', 'write', 'inplace', 'add'}, how to assign to in_grad
        out_grad : list of NDArray, gradient w.r.t. output data.
        in_grad : list of NDArray, gradient w.r.t. input data. This is the output buffer.
        """
        label = in_data[1]
        pred = out_data[0]
        # move to GPU context if needed
        class_scales = self.class_scales.as_in_context(label.context)
        dx = pred - mx.nd.one_hot(label, len(class_scales))
        # find a weight based on a label of an example
        scale_factor = (class_scales[label]).reshape((pred.shape[0],1))
        #apply scaling
        rescaled_dx = scale_factor * dx
        self.assign(in_grad[0], req[0], rescaled_dx)


@mx.operator.register("weighted_softmax_ce_loss")
class WeightedSoftmaxCrossEntropyLossProp(mx.operator.CustomOpProp):
    def __init__(self, class_weights):
        super(WeightedSoftmaxCrossEntropyLossProp, self).__init__(True)
        self.class_weights = class_weights

    def list_arguments(self):
        return ['data', 'label']

    def list_outputs(self):
        return ['output']

    def infer_shape(self, in_shapes):
        """Calculate output shapes from input shapes. This can be
        omited if all your inputs and outputs have the same shape.

        in_shapes : list of shape. Shape is described by a tuple of int.
        """
        data_shape = in_shapes[0]
        output_shape = data_shape
        # return 3 lists representing inputs shapes, outputs shapes, and aux data shapes.
        return (in_shapes), (output_shape,), ()

    def create_operator(self, ctx, in_shapes, in_dtypes):
        #  create and return the CustomOp class.
        return WeightedSoftmaxCrossEntropyLoss(self.class_weights)
```

To use it, you would need to create a model that uses this custom operation instead of regular SoftmaxOutput. Here is the model code:

```
import logging
import mxnet as mx
# it is important to import this file, even it is not directly used in the code below
import WeightedSoftmaxCrossEntropyLoss

batch_size = 100
# define a string of weights - one weight for each class, starting from the '0' class
class_weights_values = '5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1'

mnist = mx.test_utils.get_mnist()
train_iter = mx.io.NDArrayIter(mnist['train_data'], mnist['train_label'], batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_iter = mx.io.NDArrayIter(mnist['test_data'], mnist['test_label'], batch_size)

data = mx.sym.var('data')
label_names = mx.symbol.Variable("softmax_label")

data = mx.sym.flatten(data=data)

fc1 = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=data, num_hidden=15)
act1 = mx.sym.Activation(data=fc1, act_type="relu")
fc2 = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=act1, num_hidden=10) # MNIST has 10 classes
# Weighted Softmax
weighted_softmax = mx.sym.Custom(fc2, label_names, op_type='weighted_softmax_ce_loss', class_weights=class_weights_values, name='out')
# Making sure it is used as a loss funciton
mlp = mx.sym.MakeLoss(weighted_softmax)

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # logging to stdout
# create a trainable module on CPU
mlp_model = mx.mod.Module(symbol=mlp, context=mx.cpu(), label_names=['softmax_label'])
mlp_model.fit(train_iter,  # train data
              eval_data=val_iter,  # validation data
              optimizer='sgd',  # use SGD to train
              optimizer_params={'learning_rate':0.1},  # use fixed learning rate
              eval_metric='acc',  # report accuracy during training
              batch_end_callback = mx.callback.Speedometer(batch_size, 100), # output progress for each 100 data batches
              num_epoch=1)  # train for at most 10 dataset passes
```

I hope this will work for you. I haven't tried to use the results of the training, and maybe it is not working as you would expect. So, please, feel free to adjust this code as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe orthogonal to the question; but if you use softmax together with cross entropy loss, it is then trivial to add sample weights, see: http://d2p0dj726sqh0a.cloudfront.net/api/gluon/_autogen/mxnet.gluon.loss.SoftmaxCrossEntropyLoss.html